# Atheros Wireless Adapter LED Doesn't Turn Off

Tags: wireless, networking, 14.04, atheros

I know this is kind of a nit-pick but I would still like it solved.  My Wireless LED is always on, even if WiFi is turned off.  I have confirmed that when I turn WiFi off in the OS, the transmit power goes to 0 just like it should.  I also confirmed that in this state the ifconfig command doesn't list wlan0, only my loopback and eth0 interfaces just as it should.  The LED remains lit up though.

Anyone know a way to change this?  It isn't a huge deal, but I often will turn off WiFi if I'm going to be in an area where I can't use it to save power and an visual identification of if it is off or not would be nice.  As a side note in 13.04 and previous, the LED worked just fine.

I have seen a few other questions like this but have yet to see any solutions.  My computer is an ASUS EeePC 1005HAB and does not have Bluetooth.

Comment: I'm also experiencing this on a Dell Vostro V131 since I upgrade to Xubuntu 14.04. The LED previously would turn off when wifi was disabled. Hardware detail: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285